# Kali Linux 2.0 Nmap Tools

Tags: linux, nmap

I'm learning to use Kali Linux to scan for online networks using nmap commands. The basic command here is nmap -sS /24 .

I have a question about this nmap commands:

In my house, i have 2 routers

+The first router has Ipv4 : 192.168.1.1

+The Second router has Ipv4: 192.168.15.1

Let's assume that i can't connect to the second router because i don't know the password is. But if i want to know what is the ipv4 address (or default gateway) of the second router ,what command should i use in Kali Linux ? Or it's just impossible to do so ?

Comment: You can sniff ARP packets through wireshark and even If you are not connected to second Router, You will get it's IP Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that can be done using `nmap` as you need to be in a LAN network with that router. But this can be accomplished using **`Wireshark`** tool or any other tool that can capture network packets or basically is a `packet filter tool`.

***[WireShark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)*** is a tool used to analyze packet filters in the Network. It can filter packets according to IP Address , protocol and other parameters. One of the protocols It can filter is **[ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)** (Address Resolution Protocol) that maps IPv4 address to MAC Address in any Network.

So, By applying `ARP` Filter, you can get a list of ARP packets transmitted by all devices nearby going through air. From this list You can see the IP Address and MAC Address by expanding the `ARP Request section`(shown in screenshot below) after selecting any row.

[image: Wireshark ARP Filter]

Have a look at this [Wireshark Tutorial : ARP packets](https://youtu.be/xNbdeyEI-nE?t=326) & [this one too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUmHdVeBBNc). If you are Learning Tools on Kali Linux for Penetration Testing and Hacking Stuffs, this tool is one of the best to learn.

Comment: Sorry for my very late reply. I'm so busy with my study schedule that i forgot about my topic. 

Anyway,your answer to my question is clearly and easy to understand. I have been learning to use wireshark for about 2 months and it seems that i can only capture packets which flow IN MY NETWORK (which mean the router i'm connecting to).But the ARP you said is the one i did not try before.Much i know about wireshark  's filter are the TCP,HTTP,TLSv1.2,... 

Btw ,the links in your comment are also helpful.Tks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`nmap` or Kali won't give you information on the routing table of another device. If you are connected to the second router, you might do a `traceroute` to see how the traffic is flowing, and infer information about the second router's routing table from that.

If your router has SNMP enabled, you can walk OID `.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21` for routing table information.

Comment: Traceroute in Kali Linux,for some reasons,it shows the same result as nmap (plus some options). I once used traceroute command,accidentally,it shows a table of Hexadecimal (just like in wireshark if you know about this software). After that,i have retried so many times but the result  won't be the same Hexadecimal .Instead,it shows me information about MAC-address,TCP-ports,HTTP-ports,...